# "Exceeded the number of Feed Attachments allowed for type Link" when trying to insert FeedAttachment

Tags: rest-api, chatter, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate feed attachments from one ORG to another but receiving this error:

```json
{
  "statusCode": "LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
  "message": "Exceeded the number of Feed Attachments allowed for type Link",
  "fields": []
}
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```json
{
  "attributes": {
    "type": "FeedAttachment",
    "url": "/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/FeedAttachment"
  },
  "FeedEntityId": "0D51s0000078PqDBAA",
  "Type": "Link",
  "RecordId": null,
  "Title": "zoom.link",
  "Value": "https://zoom.us/j/186286572"
}
```

The ORG has plenty of data & file storage available.

Google isn't returning any results for this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked this page: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_limits_general.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null ?

Comment: You can create only one link attachment (FeedAttachment of type Link) per feed item. It is likely you are trying to attach more than one attachment. Check the feed ID and see if it already has attachment.

Comment: @manjit5190 your comment lead me in the right direction.  Turns out when I create the parent `FeedItem` with `type=LinkPost` it was automatically also creating a `FeedItemAttachment`... Thus when I went to sync the attachments, they error out because a link already exists...